# Displaying JSON data posts for blog using just the post id

Tags: php, json

I have a page named 'posts_list.php' containing a list of blog posts retrieved form a JSON API all which have id, title, image etc . I have a link on this page that goes to another page called 'post.php' as below:

```
<a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $post->id ?> ">
```

Using the GET method I can retrieve the 'id'  of the post clicked by the user using:

```
<?php $postId = $_GET['id']; ?>
```

What I want to do now is display just the JSON post on the post.php that corresponds with the id retrieved from the link on posts_list.php

I know that with SQl you would use a where clause, but being new to JSON Im not sure if this is possible. What would I need to do to achieve this with php and JSON

it also has this info

```
/v1/blogs/@blog/@id
```

@blog - blog identifier
@id - blog post ID

Comment: It would depend on what your JSON looks like... can you post a sample of it? You said you are using a JSON API... it doesn't have a way to retrieve a single post by ID?

Comment: Hop this helps"posts":[  
      {  
         "type":"post",
           "id":40044,
            "nicename":"gfdgf",
            "display_name":"name",
            "user_url":"",
            "posts_url":"https:\/\/url",
            "meta":{  
               "description":"",
               "first_name":"fred smith",
               "last_name":"last name",
               "nickname":"nick name"
            }
         },

         "is_sticky":false,
         "id":5267,
         
         "excerpt":"details",
         "meta":[ 

         ..etc

Comment: The API doesn't offer any way to retrieve a post by ID?

Comment: have edited post